# rails before_create causing nil id when rendering 'show' view from create post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I have a rails model that belongs_to a parent class. When the 'new' view form is submitted, the post to #create is made to insert a new model. In the model.rb I have a before_create callback that sets a starting value for a field. In the model-controller create method, I create the record and redirect to a 'show' view for the new record. The problem is that the record id passed to the url is always nil. **If I comment out the before_create statement then it works every time.** What am I missing here? Also, what is the best way to set a starting value for a field? I am guessing in the db model migration or validation but the before_create method seems like it applies for this functionality

```
@service = @account.services.create
   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> #<Service id: nil, account_id: 31, date: nil, default_lawn_cost: nil, cost: nil, description: nil, created_at: "2015-05-02 16:48:39", updated_at: "2015-05-02 16:48:39", paid: false>
>> @customer.accounts.create
   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "accounts" ("customer_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "total", "active") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["customer_id", 14], ["created_at", "2015-05-02 16:48:50.524798"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-02 16:48:50.524798"], ["total", 0.0], ["active", "t"]]
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> #<Account id: 34, customer_id: 14, default_address: nil, address: nil, city: nil, state: nil, zip: nil, balance: nil, lawn_cost: nil, created_at: "2015-05-02 16:48:50", updated_at: "2015-05-02 16:48:50", note: nil, active: true, total: #<BigDecimal:4d3a668,'0.0',9(36)>, tax: nil>


class ServicesController < ApplicationController

   def new
     setup
     @service = @account.services.build
   end

   def create
      @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
      @account = @customer.accounts.find(params[:account_id])
      @service = @account.services.create(service_params)
      if @service.valid?
         add_service_to_account(@account, @service)
             @account.save
             redirect_to customer_account_service_path(@customer, @account, @service)
          else
             render 'new'
          end
       end
    end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :account

   before_create :unset_paid

   validates :cost, format: { allow_blank: true, with: /\A\$?\d{1,4}(\.\d{0,2})?\Z/ }

   def unset_paid
      self.paid = false
   end
end
```

And here is the view error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in ServicesController#create
No route matches {:account_id=>"31", :action=>"show", :controller=>"services", :customer_id=>"14", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
Extracted source (around line #21):
```

Line 21

```
redirect_to customer_account_service_path(@customer, @account, @service)
```

Relevant routes:

```
 new_customer_account_service GET    /customers/:customer_id/accounts/:account_id/services/new(.:format)      services#new
edit_customer_account_service GET    /customers/:customer_id/accounts/:account_id/services/:id/edit(.:format) services#edit
     customer_account_service GET    /customers/:customer_id/accounts/:account_id/services/:id(.:format)      services#show
                              PATCH  /customers/:customer_id/accounts/:account_id/services/:id(.:format)      services#update
                              PUT    /customers/:customer_id/accounts/:account_id/services/:id(.:format)      services#update
                              DELETE /customers/:customer_id/accounts/:account_id/services/:id(.:format)      services#destroy


class CreateServices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :services do |t|
      t.references :account, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.date :date
      t.boolean :default_lawn_cost
      t.decimal :cost
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What if you try to create your model in the console? What error do you get?

Comment: could you post some code

Comment: can you post any & all relevant code from the model and controller involved?

Comment: In the rails console the id is nil as well. There is no error

Comment: are you trying to create an account in the services controller?  what's add_service_to_account?

Comment: There are method that update the account fields. add_service_to_account just adds the service cost to the account balance. It doesn't call any database queries

Comment: Is there a recommendation for updating the parent class fields? Because conceptually I think it makes more sense to update the owner classes field when the object is created. In other words, The Account balance should be updated by the Service cost on creation?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're trying to do. Sorry, for all the edit requests I'm just trying to understand. Could you add your new action and the relevant routes please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I still can't figure out what's happening. Try visiting this page for tips on debugging: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: Does `id` has `auto_incerement` on database?

Comment: I think that rails does the auto id on default but I added the db migration for the table anyway. Like I said, commenting out the before_create in the service model fixes the issue. There is another migration that adds a field but it isn't relevant. This seems like a simple thing I guess my approach is wrong. How does one accomplish the task from my previous comment in a DRY Rails way?

Comment: what is @service.errors.to_a when it fails? Hopefully you're using better errors

Comment: I added a exception handler at the redirect method and @service.errors.to_a returned empty [] on the server output using puts and inspect.   I don't think it is a validation error. The url is wrong because the id is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of why I really really don't like ActiveRecord callbacks; they're too clever and create weird situations that leave you pulling your hair out about some bug with no clear cause.

If a `before_create` or `before_save` callback returns `false`, it will **cancel the database operation about to be performed.** See [this guide page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#halting-execution) on how this works. I'm guessing that's what's tripping you up in this case, because as soon as you try to create the record, the `unset_paid` record is called and accidentally cancels the entire save/create operation. That, in turn, means that the newly not-created record has no `id`, so when you try to redirect to the record's URL, the path turns into `/accounts/nil`.

There's advice floating around the Rails world lately that you should always use `save!` and `create!` by default, rather than their un-banged versions, because the former will raise an error if the operation fails. If you had used `@account.save!`, you would have immediately seen an exception that pointed you towards the heart of the problem (namely, something went wrong while trying to save the record) rather than leaving you wondering if your routes are enchanted.

Hope that helped!